# Указатель this в классе

Tags: c++

Насколько я понял, когда читал про this, что указатель необходим по большей части, когда мы используем несколько объектов одного и того же класса. Однако встает вопрос, нужно ли в конструкторе по умолчанию или с параметрами присваивать значение через указатель (ниже код примера

```
class A{
public:
  A(int in);
private:
  int tmp;
};

A::A(int in){
  this->tmp=in; // или же tmp=in;
}
```

Comment: "...указатель необходим по большей части, когда мы используем несколько объектов одного и того же класса..." - это какая-то ерунда. `this` - это скрытый параметр каждого нестатического метода класса. На `this` фундаментально построена вся функциональность классов. Без него - никуда, независимо от того, сколько у нас объектов.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/993352/2110496

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. Вернее - не обязательно. Это было бы нужно, если бы параметр назывался так же как член класса:

```
class A{
  public:
    A(int tmp);
  private:
    int tmp;
}

A::A(int tmp){
  this->tmp = tmp;
}
```

Comment: В остальных же функциях класса указатель this необходим? Или также необязателен?

Comment: @John он нужен только там, где возможен конфликт имен

Comment: В данном случае надо использовать инициализацию, а не присваивание, тогда `this` не нужен: `A::A(int tmp):tmp(tmp){}`. Ну и конфликта имен нет в Вашем примере, есть сокрытие.

Answer (score 5):

Это больше вопрос конвенции кода. `this` нужно использовать, если имя скрывает другой параметр.

Ну или при работе с шаблонами:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
   int i;
};

template<class T>
struct B : A<T> {

    int foo() {
        return this->i;
    }

};

int main() {
    B<int> b;
    b.foo();
}
```

Без `this->` не скомпилится, т.к. нужно сообщить явно компилятору, что используется `i` из `A<T>`.

Comment: Переключились со джавы? ;)

Comment: `using A<T>::i;`

Comment: @alexolut я начинал с C++ в своё время. К счастью, перешёл на Java (:

Comment: @vp_arth или так, да.

Answer (score 2):

Помимо уже сказанного в других ответах, наличие `this->` сразу говорит читателю кода, что речь именно о члене класса, а не о какой-то другой глобальной/локальной переменной. Подобную проблему, правда лучше решать соглашениями по коду, например, начинать все имена членов с префикса `m` или добавлять суффикс в виде подчеркивания `_`. Но и это бывает не нужно, если работать исключительно в современных IDE с достаточным уровнем анализа кода — члены класса будут иметь отдельное от других сущностей выделение цветом/стилем шрифта.

Comment: А я знаете, люблю писать this->. Например, мне больше нравится this->swap(other) или std::swap(this->m_number, other->m_number) чем то же самое без this. Конечно, использование this в таких ситуациях абсолютно ни на что не влияет, но без него как будто «обрубки» получаются. Короче, это у кого какой почеркъ

Comment: @Jenssen да, мой ответ в основном о *стиле* кода, нежели о правилах самого языка. Ну и ещё после `this->` может сработать автоподстановка в некоторых IDE, что тоже удобно.